# turbo_stream_from suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm running a rails 6 app that is heavily using all sorts of hotwire goodness. I noticed that after a deploy my turbo streams stopped working.

In my view I've got

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "#{dom_id(@class)}_lesson" %>
```

Which in theory should start listening on an ActionCable channel, however, that is not happening. I can't see any message in my console that confirms that the action cable channel is connected and therefore any turbo broadcast I do is not being received by my frontend

```
broadcast_update_to "school_class_#{id}_lesson", target: "question_#{question.id}_lock",
        partial: "lessons/lock_overlay"
```

The broadcast tries to do what its told as I can see from my server logs

```
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to school_class_15_lesson: "<turbo-stream action=\"update\" target=\"question_58_lock\"><template></template></turbo-stream>"
```

However, since the stream is not active the frontend is not receiving the update.

There's only one thing that may have broken this in the latest code changes. I wired sidekiq to handle my background jobs. This means that I added a new `redis.rb` initializer

```
$redis = Redis.new

url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
end
```

Which doesn't look like it would break anything. To add some context, this is my `cable.yml` file

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

staging:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: cable_staging
  ssl_params: {
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
  }

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: cable_production
  ssl_params: {
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
  }
```

Can you think of anything that may have broken the existing setup that had been working for over a year?

Comment: Having the same problem here, is this related to cable.yml SSL configuration?